# Handle Different Signing Provisioning File in AppCenter Build

Tags: ios, react-native, visual-studio-app-center, appcenter

I've joined a company that uses AppCenter to build their React Native App.

I have in my XCode configuration two Signing Capability

- Debug - AdHoc destined to test bug
- Release - AppStore destined to app store

My provisioning profiles are set depending on these config.
It works well

[image: XCode configuration]

Otherwise inside AppCenter configuration build for iOS, i cannot choose wether i want to generate an adhoc build or a release build.

you can find there screenshots showing XCode configuration and AppCenter configuration.
Documentation is very unclear.

[image: AppCenter configuration]

Thanks for your help